# How to bundle Nmap and Wireshark with app?

Tags: java, windows, wireshark, nmap

I've written a java app. It depends on Nmap, Wireshark and other command line tools which it invokes via a DOS prompt on Windows.

If I'd like to make an installer for the app, how can I make sure that Nmap and Wireshark are installed on the user's computer, and the Windows "Path" Environmental Variable is updated with their install directories, so that when I invoke the DOS prompts from my app, the commands execute correctly?

Comment: BTW - what is the motivation for choosing Java to write this very Windows oriented (command line based) software?  Wouldn't an API from MS (e.g. .Net) be better suited to this task (including the installer for it)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class to check if the application already exists. Simply over the command line run query something like:

```
ftype | find "Wireshark"
```

and check the returned string, either it will have the path to wireshark binary or error message. Once it is there, you can invoke wireshark commands from this abs path.

If not, then you can package them as *portable* tool packaged in your jar file. You can unjar this file at run time, and through process builder, invoke this tool and run wire-shark dependent tasks. Same goes for *nmap*.

I hope this gives you the idea how to go about it.